# #Naming items not in your inventory

Tags: nethack

Is it possible to `#name` items  that are not your inventory? Loadstones auto-curse themselves when you pick them up, is there any way to `#name` one so I know when I run into one later?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot `#name` items except those in your inventory. When you use the command `#name`, it only takes an inventory letter as an argument.

A good strategy is to simply never pick up a gray stone unless you are sure it is not a loadstone or to pick it up, uncurse it somehow, `#name` it, and drop it again. You can always test whether any individual gray stone is a loadstone by kicking it without wearing boots of kicking. If it moves, it's not a loadstone. Then if you do pick it up, you can `#name` it "not loadstone" or something more specific if you can figure it out. Then if you ever have three different names for different gray stones, any unnamed gray stone is a loadstone. You can check what items you have names for with [<kbd>\</kbd>](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Discoveries).

There is more information about [loadstones](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Loadstone) and [`#name`](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/Name) on the wiki.